# C++ error: Use of deleted function in move constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class Container {
    int * m_Data;
public:
    Container() {
        //Allocate an array of 20 int on heap
        m_Data = new int[20];

        std::cout << "Constructor: Allocation 20 int" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Container() {
        if (m_Data) {
            delete[] m_Data;
            m_Data = NULL;
        }
        std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    Container(const Container & obj) {
        //Allocate an array of 20 int on heap
        m_Data = new int[20];

        //Copy the data from passed object
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            m_Data[i] = obj.m_Data[i];

        std::cout << "Copy Constructor: Allocation 20 int" << std::endl;
    }

    // will give error on adding
    Container(Container&&) = delete;

};

// Create am object of Container and return
Container getContainer() 
{
    Container obj;
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    // Create a vector of Container Type
    std::vector<Container> vecOfContainers;

    //Add object returned by function into the vector
    vecOfContainers.push_back(getContainer());

    return 0;
}
```

I have written above code just as practice to verify that copy constructor is called when object is returned from getContainer() even though it is an rvalue.

I know that if user defined copy constructor exists, then the compiler will not declare a move constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class with the signature T::T(T&&). Still i decided to add the line "Container(Container&&) = delete;" and get the below error during compilation::

```
moveconstructorIntro.cpp: In function ‘Container getContainer()’:
moveconstructorIntro.cpp:44:12: error: use of deleted function 
‘Container::Container(Container&&)’
     return obj;
            ^
moveconstructorIntro.cpp:36:5: error: declared here
     Container(Container&&) = delete;
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/x86_64-redhat-
linux/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from moveconstructorIntro.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = Container; _Args = {Container}; _Tp = Container]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:254:4:   required from ‘static typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::_S_construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = Container; _Args = {Container}; _Alloc = std::allocator<Container>; typename std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__construct_helper<_Tp, _Args>::value, void>::type = void]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:393:57:   required from ‘static decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, _Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = Container; _Args = {Container}; _Alloc = std::allocator<Container>; decltype (_S_construct(__a, __p, (forward<_Args>(std::allocator_traits::construct::__args)...)) = <type error>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/vector.tcc:97:40:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {Container}; _Tp = Container; _Alloc = std::allocator<Container>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:920:36:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = Container; _Alloc = std::allocator<Container>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Container]’
moveconstructorIntro.cpp:52:45:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted 
function ‘Container::Container(Container&&)’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
moveconstructorIntro.cpp:36:5: error: declared here
     Container(Container&&) = delete;
     ^
```

what was the reason for the error?

Please don't try to find any use case for what I am doing over here. I just started writing code in C++ and trying to get a grasp.

Comment: 'delete' is a reserved word in C++. You have a syntax error

Comment: @RobertKock - It is reserved. And it's also used correctly here. Despite the unfortunate consequences of using it.

Comment: Return local variable will invoke move constructor, which is deleted.

Comment: OK. I missed something apparently. Haven't been using C++ for a while

Comment: @SergeyA: 2017? Check your tzdata file.

Comment: @erenon fixed it a 10 secs ago, and then seen your comment.

Answer (score 5):

When you explicitly deleted the move constructor, you made it available for overload resolution.

Than, when returning local argument by value, move constructor was selected as a better overload candidate (over copy constructor), but could not be used as it is deleted.

Keep in mind, not declaring move constructor and explicitly deleting it yields a different result in regards to the overload resolution process!

**EDIT**

While what I was saying above is true, as it happens, the particular report reported by compiler in this code is in the other area, namely, a move attempt happening when the value is pushed back into the container. Same thing happens there - a move constructor is selected during overload resolution, but than can not be used as it is deleted.

Comment: "move constructor was selected as a better overload candidate (over copy constructor)" Why? The local variable is still an lvalue, isn't it?

Comment: @songyuanyao, there is a special rule. Returning from local parameter or local variable is a candidate for move constructor when available. This is why you should not do `return std::move(ret)` in your return statements.

Comment: @songyuanyao - Specifically, [this rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3).

Comment: [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MuFxgcW6qZuWpLlD) said the error comes from `vecOfContainers.push_back(getContainer());`, because the rvalue returned by `getContainer()` can't be moved into the `vector`.

Comment: @StoryTeller "If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (possibly cv-qualified), overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue." Two-stage overload resolution means, if the move constructor fails, then copy constructor should be selected instead, isn't it?

Comment: @songyuanyao it just decided to report this, not really sure how diagnostics are implemented. You can see in this example https://godbolt.org/g/Q6US2t how a simple return without any containers triggers the same problem.

Comment: @songyuanyao - That's what I think it should be too, as do the Clang developers. [But then there's this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47881013/constructor-called-on-return-statement). Ostensibly overload resolution doesn't fail, it just pick a "bad" function.

Comment: @StoryTeller see my example which clearly shows how it works.

Comment: @StoryTeller This is weird, the sample in the linked post does compile with [gcc8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iy0i6QXWqmDe6NEz) too; that means both gcc and clang behave wrongly on this issue..

Comment: @SergeyA - Yes, Iv'e seen you example. It's pretty much the same as in the post I linked to. There's a difference between GCC and Clang on this. Barry's answer is a good read, I think.

Comment: @songyuanyao See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions. Overload resolution doesn't fail, selecting the deleted function is the result of overload resolution.

Comment: @songyuanyao - Interesting. Seems GCC 8 agrees with Clang now (while 7.2 doesn't).

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, that's why OP's getting the error; he/she seems using gcc4.8.2.

Comment: @songyuanyao  guaranteed copy elision kicks in?

Comment: @StoryTeller can you post a link to the code with compiler args? I would believe guaranteed copy elision might be happening.

Comment: @SergeyA But I think [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is mandatory only when returning a prvalue.

Comment: @SergeyA - Well, Here's [GCC8 in C++14 pedantic-errors](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CQFWWq2UG7GKNmAh). Not a peep. If you switch to GCC 7, than both c++14 and c++17 mode would cause it to fail.

Comment: @StoryTeller interesting. This question quickly overgrows! To be honest, I am not sure what to think now. My reading of the Standard tells me it should be an error, compilers disagree... What is your take?

Comment: @SergeyA - To be perfectly honest, I'm torn. I always thought Clang had it right in spirit, that an optimization should not make an otherwise correct program ill-formed (explicitly deleted c'tor be damned). But then again, I totally see how a strict reading of the standard makes this ill-formed. I'm equally baffled that GCC changed its take on this between 7 and 8 (though that may be a temporary bug).